# What better way to implement OnClickListner on row Item in List Adabpter

Tags: android, listview

I have implemented custom adapter and having multiple views (ImageView, TextView) in List row. I want to set listener on each of these.

This what I have done

```
if (containerRow == null)  { 
viewHolder.item.setOnClickListener(new OnImageViewClickListener(position, context, viewHolder));
}
```

Now this gives me wrong position in OnImageViewClickListener as viewHolder.item.setOnClickListener is getting called only once when (containerRow == null). If I do this in else part than lot of listener object creation for multiple items (ImageView, TextView) and that number of rows (Am I right?)

As per my understanding I cannot achieve this is in ListView's setOnItemClickListener as there I cannot get the item of the on which user has clicked.

Please suggest me some neat way to implement listener on these row items and to receive right position.

Answer (score 1):

Set the position as a TAG for each view and set the listener on each clickable view

Define the listener as inner class, and get the tag from the view

```
if (containerRow == null)  { 
    ....
    ....
    viewHolder.txv.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
    viewHolder.img.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
    .....
    .....
}else{
    viewHolder = containerRow.getTag();
}

viewHolder.txv.setTag(position);
viewHolder.img.setTag(position);
```

The OnClickListener:

```
private View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Integer position = (Integer) v.getTag();
        // you have the correct position
        switch(v.getId()){
        ......
        ......
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: thanks for this. It looks very clean approach to me. Let me try this and will update you soon.

Comment: :( not eligible to do so now. Will do it later.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work where ListItem is a POJO containing the data for the list item...

```
public class ListItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListItem>
{
    private static final String TAG    = "ListItemAdapter";
    private Activity            mContext;
    private int                 mLayoutResourceId;
    private List<ListItem> mItems = null;

static class ViewHolder
{
    public TextView  text1;
    public TextView  text2;
    public ImageView image;
}

public ListItemAdapter(Activity context, int textViewResourceId, List<ListItem> items)
{
    super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
    mContext = context;
    mLayoutResourceId = textViewResourceId;
    mItems = items;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = mContext.getLayoutInflater();
        v = inflater.inflate(mLayoutResourceId, parent, false);

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.text1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        viewHolder.text1.setOnClickListener(new ItemClickListener(position));
        viewHolder.text2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
        viewHolder.text2.setOnClickListener(new ItemClickListener(position));
        viewHolder.image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.icon);
        viewHolder.image.setOnClickListener(new ItemClickListener(position));

        v.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    ListItem item = mItems.get(position);
    Log.v(TAG, item.toString());

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();

    String text = item.getText1();
    holder.text1.setText(text);

    text = item.getText2();
    holder.text2.setText(text);

    Drawable img = item.getImage();
    Log.v(TAG, "image : " + img);

    holder.image.setImageDrawable(img);
    return v;
}

class ItemClickListener implements View.OnClickListener
{
    int position;

    public ItemClickListener(int pos)
    {
        this.position = pos;
    }

    public void onClick(View v)
    {

        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Item clicked in row - " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    };
}
```

}